# How to create composite Json object working with Typicode Json Server

Tags: jquery, json, nested, json-server

I am working in a Web Application using jQuery and  I am confused about the JSON format. For the server I am using a [restful Json Server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server).

The problem is that don't know what is the problem. The error is that the Json format that i post to the server (HTTP POST with Ajax) seems to be incorrect. I will try to explain this step by step.

The initial situation of the Json Server (at http://localhost:3000/db) is:

```
{
   "userRecipes": []
}
```

Now, I create a Json object as follows:

```
var example2json = {
    "description":"some desc",
    "trigger":{
        "triggerType":"exampleType",
        "field1":"something1",
        "field2":"something2",
        "field3":"something3"
    }
};
```

And send this fictional object three times to the server with this:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/userRecipes",
    data: example2json,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        $('#recipedDescriptionModal').modal('hide');
        url = "#SuccessRepice";
        window.location.replace(url);

    }
});
```

After this the Json server status results to be:

```
{
  "userRecipes": [
    {
      "description": "some desc",
      "trigger[triggerType]": "exampleType",
      "trigger[field1]": "something1",
      "trigger[field2]": "something2",
      "trigger[field3]": "something3",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "description": "some desc",
      "trigger[triggerType]": "exampleType",
      "trigger[field1]": "something1",
      "trigger[field2]": "something2",
      "trigger[field3]": "something3",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "description": "some desc",
      "trigger[triggerType]": "exampleType",
      "trigger[field1]": "something1",
      "trigger[field2]": "something2",
      "trigger[field3]": "something3",
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Why the Json format changes? When I want to access to a field I have to do:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data.userRecipes[1]["trigger[triggerType]"]));
```

but I would do it in this way:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data.userRecipes[1].trigger.triggerType));
```

I'm sure to go wrong somewhere, but do not know where.

The only suspect that I have is that I create incorrectly the Json (some object nested in the elements of an array) OR there's something that I don't know about this Json Server.

Comment: I tried also to use `data: JSON.stringify(example2json)` on the AJAX POST, but in there Json Server I see this literally: `{
      "{\"description\":\"some desc\",\"trigger\":{\"triggerType\":\"exampleType\",\"field1\":\"something1\",\"field2\":\"something2\",\"field3\":\"something3\"}}": "",
      "id": 4
    }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The type of the POST content had to be specified:

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
```

and so, from this:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/userRecipes",
    data: example2json,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        $('#recipedDescriptionModal').modal('hide');
        url = "#SuccessRepice";
        window.location.replace(url);

    }
});
```

to that:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/userRecipes",
    data: example2json,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', //This is the money shot ✅
    success: function(response) {
        $('#recipedDescriptionModal').modal('hide');
        url = "#SuccessRepice";
        window.location.replace(url);

    }
});
```

in my case, I confounded the two fields `dataType` with `contentType`.

The `dataType` field is used to specify the data format of the ***response***.

The `contentType` is used to specify data format of the ***request***.